# how to get all coupon code which can apply on cart page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, coupon-codes

How to get all coupon code which can apply on cart page in magento 2

`$getRules = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->getCollection();`

using the above code i get the all list of coupon codes. I want to display coupon code which can apply

Comment: I want to show list of valid coupon on cart page

Answer (score 3):

There is already a full fledged free extension available on magento's marketplace and github

**magento:** https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-couponlist.html

**github:** https://github.com/ambab-infotech/couponlist

This might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have created block to get cart items using checkout session file name is CustomSession.php

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
}

public function getProducts()
    {
        $item = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
       return $item;
    }
```

than overriding the coupon.phtml file

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $CatalogSession = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Session');
        $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Contact\Block\CustomSession');  
        $SalesRule = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule');
        $getRules = $SalesRule->getCollection();
        $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

        $products = $blockObj->getProducts(); // this will also work using custom session block
foreach ($products as $product) {
        foreach ($getRules as $rule) {
$rules = $SalesRule->load($rule->getId());
$item->setProduct($product);
$validate = $rules->getActions()->validate($product);
            if ($validate == true) {

                echo "coupon -".$rule->getCode()."'>".$rule->getCode()." - ".$rule->getDescription()." coupon";
                 echo "<br>";
                # code...
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as mentioned above by Yash I am already using this on my project this one is really cool. (Awesome work Yash [Ambab] )

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/303127/85990